# How to reuse a component in vue inside a dynamic component tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have written some view components using single file components.

There is one master component that will have a tab control that should switch through the other components. I want all of the tabs to stay alive as you switch so you can come back. Additionally some of the tabs should consist of the same component but will display different data. The number of tabs should be dynamic as input data to the page will cause it to span more tabs.

I know that vue provides a switchable component and furthermore provides keep-alive tags to sustain the state of the component so I have code like this:

```
<keep-alive>
   <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
</keep-alive>
```

In the vue code I setup an array with some default tabs which I later want to add to, along with a function to return the currentTabComponent and populate the screen

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import MessageLog from './components/MessageLog.vue';

components: {
            Home,
            MessageLog
},
data: function () {
    return {
        selectedTab: 0,
        currentTab: "Home",
        tabs: ['Home', 'MessageLog'],
        tabComponents: new Map([["Home", Home], ["MessageLog", MessageLog]])
    }
},
computed: {
    currentTabComponent: function () {
        this.currentTab = this.tabs[this.selectedTab];
        return this.tabComponents.get(this.currentTab);
},
methods: {
    testTab: function () {
        this.tabs.push("nextTab");
        import('./components/MessageLog.vue').then(
            result =>
            {
                result.default.name = "nextTab";
                this.tabComponents.set("nextTab", result.default);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Ideally I should be able to call testTab and have it load an INDEPENDENT component and switch to it and use it.

What happens is all this code works, but when the new tab is opened it shares state with the existing MessageLog tab, even though the component was loaded totally separately in the test tab function! I have a test button on the message log component which adds more messages and as messages are added and you swap between the two tabs with a MessageLog component the messages are all identical.

Is this some bug with the `<keep-alive>` option?

Or is this just a terrible design?

The goal would be that as tabs are created I can inject some ID into them (not shown here). Then we I have new data for that tab I can emit a message with its ID - it can then grab that message and do whatever is needed to show the new data.

Comment: It's a bit confusing but it sounds like you want to use the same component multiple times in tabs and it's not switching the data out as you would expect?  If that's the case you probably will need to bind a key to the `component` and use different keys for each one.

Comment: Could you supply a CodePen reproducing the issue?

Comment: @ Steven I think you hit the nail on the head. For my learning purposes can you explain or link to the side effect of adding the key, I can see this fixes it, but why?

Comment: @Robert Vue tries to reuse components where it can to prevent updating the dom more than necessary.  When it's comparing the components your switching out it's not likely to be able to tell the difference between the same types of components unless it has an identifier i.e. the key.  Reading the [api reference](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) on key's should give you better understanding.   There's a small section that says keying "can also be used to force replacement of an element/component instead of reusing it" which is the relevant bit for you.